# timed rectangle animation javascript

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

I want to create a game where I need a animation: First should drawed a rectangle after 5 seconds, the second rect after 5 seconds, the third after 5 too, the fourth after 5 too, the 6-10 rects after 4s, the 10-15 rects after 3s, the 15-20 rects after 2s and the 20-25 rects after 1 second. The rectangles came from above and should run with a speed called `recty` to the bottom. Maybe will this help:[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/jW9wd/).

```
  var x = canvasWidth / 100;
  var y = canvasHeight / 100;
  b = 5000;
     function init() {
    recty = canvasHeight / 100 * 20;
    rectx = (Math.random() *(x * 50)) + (x / 5);
    rectb = (Math.random() * (x * 40)) + x * 20;
    return setInterval(main_loop, 10);


  }


  function draw() {
    rectheight = canvasHeight / 100 * 10;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
    // draw triangles
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x * 90, y * 50);
    ctx.lineTo(x * 99, y * 60);
    ctx.lineTo(x * 99, y * 40);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();

  }

  function drawrect() {
    // draw rect
    ctx.beginPath();
    fillStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.rect(rectx, recty, rectb, rectheight);
    ctx.fill();

  }

  function update() {
    recty += 1;
    if (recty > canvasHeight) {
      recty = -rectheight;
      rectx = (Math.random() *(x * 50)) + (x / 5);
      rectb = (Math.random() *(x * 50)) + (x / 5);
      b -=1000;
    }
    if (recty > canvasHeight) {
      recty -= 1;


    }
  }



  function main_loop() {
    draw();
    update();
    collisiondetection();
    drawrect();
  }


  init();
  setInterval ( drawrect, b );
```

Comment: And your problem being?

Comment: to draw a new rectangle after the said times, wich run from above to bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern browsers have a built-in timer: `requestAnimationFrame`.

A requestAnimationFrame loop will fire about every 16ms and will be given a very precise `currentTime` argument. You start the timing loop with: `requestAnimationFrame(Timer);`. The loop will execute only once for each requestAnimationFrame you issue, so you put a requestAnimationFrame inside the loop itself to keep it running.

Here's an example timing loop that calculates the elapsed time since the timing loop started:

```
// variable used to calculate elapsed time
var lastTime;

// start the first timing loop
requestAnimationFrame(Timer);

function Timer(time){

    // request another timing loop
    // Note: requestAnimationFrame fires only once,
    //       so you must request another loop inside 
    //       each current loop
    requestAnimationFrame(Timer);

    // if this is the very first loop, initialize `lastTime`
    if(!lastTime){lastTime=time;}

    // calculate elapsed time since the last loop
    var elapsedTime=time-lastTime;
}
```

To make your rectangles "time aware" you can create a javascript object for each rectangle that defines all that's need to draw that rectangle at the desired timing interval. Then use this javascript object to draw the rectangle at the desired position after the desired time interval.

Example of rectangle object properties

- position of the rect: `x,y`
- the time interval to wait before next updating the rect's position: `interval`
- the distance to move the rect during an update: `moveByX, moveByY`

Here's example code and a Demo:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var rects=[]
rects.push({x:10,y:10,moveByX:5,interval:500,nextMoveTime:0});
rects.push({x:10,y:50,moveByX:5,interval:1000,nextMoveTime:0});
rects.push({x:10,y:110,moveByX:5,interval:2000,nextMoveTime:0});

var isFirstLoop=true;

// start the timing loop
requestAnimationFrame(Timer);

function Timer(currentTime){

  // request another timing loop
  // Note: requestAnimationFrame fires only once,
  //       so you must request another loop inside 
  //       each current loop
  requestAnimationFrame(Timer);

  if(isFirstLoop){
    isFirstLoop=false;
    for(var i=0;i<rects.length;i++){
      rects[i].nextMoveTime=time+rects[i].interval;
    }
  }

  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  for(var i=0;i<rects.length;i++){
    drawRect(rects[i],currentTime);
  }

}

function drawRect(r,time){
  if(time>r.nextMoveTime){
    r.x+=r.moveByX;
    r.nextMoveTime=parseInt(time+r.interval);
  }
  ctx.strokeRect(r.x,r.y,110,15);
  ctx.fillText('I move every '+r.interval+'ms',r.x+5,r.y+10);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you though about css animation? 
It can come really handy, and has a better performance than javascript.

You can use transitions on position, and even delay if you don't care about IE9 and before. If you do, you should initiate the animations with javascript by adding a class to each boxes, and that would make it cross-browser.

Bassic css mockup for this would look something like this:

```
.box{
    width:90px;height:90px;background:red;position:absolute;
    -webkit-animation: mymove 5s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: mymove 5s;
    animation-delay: 2s; 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
}
```

And then you can add rules for specific boxes, and overrule the basic box style.

```
.box-1{animation-delay:10s; -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;}
```

See jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eyqtg9wp/

Comment: CSS animations are cool, but they tend to be a bit disconnected from the code; might not make it perfectly fitting for a video game. (For instance, let's say he suddenly wants to pause the animation - probably possible in CSS, but not in a very obvious way.)